# Button pressed animation in Sprite-Kit

Tags: ios, animation, button, sprite-kit

In a Sprite-Kit game I want to animate Buttons when they were pressed. Right now the code reacts directly and to not wait till the animation is executed. Furthermore I want the button to animate back when the user wipes his finger out of the button.

```
Here my code:

-(void)addStartButton:(CGSize)size {
    self.start = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"startButton1"];
    self.start.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    self.start.name = @"start";
    [self addChild:self.start];  
}



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
   SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];


if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"start"]) {

    self.start.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"startButton2"];        

    MyScene *myScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:myScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you 2 second delay before switching to another scene:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
   SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];    

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"start"]) {
    SKAction *changeTexture = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        self.start.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"startButton2"];   
    }];
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.f];
    SKAction *presentAnotherScene = [SKAction runBlock:^{        
        MyScene *myScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:myScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
    }];
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[changeTexture,wait,presentAnotherScene]]];
    }
}
```

> Furthermore I want the button to animate back when the user wipes his finger out of the button.

This seems pointless, since you are transitioning to another scene when user presses the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"start"]) {
    startButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"startButton2"];
}else{startButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"startButton1"];}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"start"]) {
    startButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"startButton2"];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"start"]) {
        //Start Button Actions
}
```